# Find image that fit together the best

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Given a batch of images i have to find the images that fit together the best like in the example given below, but my solutions are not working:

#### Left image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrVmR.png]

#### Right image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfWwL.png]

I tried firstly with google cloud Vision API but it wasn't giving good results, then i trained a model over with ludwig but it will take forever to try all the possible combinations of images, as i have 2500 left images and 2500 right images.

is there a way to find this out or decrease the possible cases so that i can use it in my model.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify the constraints properly? Are there scale and rotation differences between the halves. Are the *"sticky out prongs"* always rectangular and with exactly 18 prongs, or are some shapes curves or ellipses or triangular?

Comment: does "best fit" always mean a filled rectangle/square? What's the error metric if a square/rectangle is only achieved with overlap  (or holes)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Like in this image (https://imgur.com/a/FBdXtYo). The no of fingers are fixed to 15 but can be tilted on an angle as well and their shape is also fixed to a rectangle or a tilted one like in the image.

Comment: @Micka Their will be a match that exist for all the images

Comment: Note: images are of different dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution looks at a pair of images. The algorithm evaluates whether the shapes in the image will mesh like a key and a lock. My answer does not attempt to align the images.

The first step is to find the contours in the images:

```
left= cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/left.png')
right = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/right.png')
# Resize
left = cv2.resize(left, (320,320))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(left, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, left_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Approximate
left_contour = left_contours[0]
epsilon = 0.005*cv2.arcLength(left_contour,True)
left_contour = cv2.approxPolyDP(left_contour,epsilon,True)
```

[image: left_contours][image: right_contours]

What is a contour? A contour is just a list of points that lie on the perimeter of a shape. The contour for a triangle will have 3 points and a length of 3. The distance between the points will be the length of each leg in the triangle.

Similarly, the distances between the peaks and valleys will match in your images. To compute this distance, I found the distance between the contour points. Because of the way that the images are aligned I only used the horizontal distance.

```
left_dx = []
for point in range(len(left_contour)-1):
    a = left_contour[point][0]
    b = left_contour[point+1][0]
    dist = a[0]-b[0]
    left_dx.append(dist)
right_dx = []
for point in range(len(right_contour)-1):
    a = right_contour[point][0]
    b = right_contour[point+1][0]
    # Use the - of the distance becuase this is the key hole, not the key
    dist = -distance(a,b)
    right_dx.append(dist)
# Reverse so they will fit
right_dx.reverse()
```

[image: dx in contours]

A this point you can sort of see that the contours line up. If you have better images, the contours will line up in this step. I used Scipy to iterpolate and check if the functions line up. If the two functions do line up, then the objects in the images will mesh.

```
left_x_values = []
for i in range(len(left_dx)): left_x_values.append(i)
x = np.array(left_x_values)
y = np.array(left_dx)
left_x_new = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(),500)
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')
left_y_smooth=f(left_x_new)
plt.plot (left_x_new, left_y_smooth,c = 'g')
```

[image: fitting]

I tried this again on a pair of images that I generated myself:

[image: right][image: left]

The contours:

[image: right_contorus test][image: left_contours test]

The distances between contour points:

[image: distances]

Fitting the contours:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a pretty good approach. Can u also add some of the code that you used to perform this, as I have no idea of OpenCV as such.

Comment: It seems interesting. how can we match with others? he has mentioned that 2500 combinations.